# Implement a querylanguage

Tags: sql, customization

I would like to create my own query language for a web api I wrote. But I have no idea where to start for it.

The language should be like SQL. For that I looked up the NHibernate code, cause I know, that they have the HQL (Hibernate Query Language) but it didn't help.

Are there any instructions or sth.? If this question is wrong here please move and/or tell me where I should ask else.

Comment: Have you ever read a parser? Language design is interesting but it's also non-trivial. If you've just written a simple web API I suggest sticking to REST.

Comment: I tried to find the parser of NHibernate and I started writing my own Interpreter for a custom language, so yeah, I know it is a lot of effort and very complicated, but it would make it easier for developers to solve. I really like the idea of e.g. FQL. The REST API is already finished, the CustomQL is just an idea and more to see as sugar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is a lot of design work, starting be answering the following question:

> Is this new Query Language going to be converted to SQL which will be
>   executed by a standard database engine, or are you going to write your
>   own database server as well?

If it's going to be converted to SQL (just like HQL) then map out the translations from your language to SQL on paper (and make sure you know the possible SQL constructs you may have to use). Once you've got that, you can start implementing it. Yes, this sounds like BDUF, but the language should be defined in one pass, I think, as it will be more consistent and easier to use if you do it that way. You can always implement it in a more Agile way once you've got that.

If you're going to write own database server, you're on your own....

Comment: I really like the idea of going by converting to SQL, would make things fairly easy. No my database is "just" SQL Azure. The only thing that will be very hard is to prevent SQL injection...

Comment: You can require that by not allowing values to be put into your query language string and specifying that they be provided as parameters. e.g. any comparison must be between two columns (as in a join) or between a column and a parameter. Similarly, that value of a SET operation must be a parameter. It's your language and you get to make the rules....

Comment: Oh right, so you would recomend doing it like this `select @var1 from @var2 where @check=@value` and then replace the values. At least for the tables I can check.

Comment: Only the where bit. The select bit is fine: select cola from tableb where colB = @param1. You can assume that cola is a column name and tableB is a table name, and colB is a column name (if they aren't, the SQL will error and you pass that on). Just don't allow colB = 'my injected SQL'

Comment: Ok, great. tricky will be the part with insert, update and delete. But maybe these will just stay over the API.

Comment: @Knerd if you're using Azure I assume C#, just wanted to say WebAPI already supports OData if you return `IQueryable`s from controllers. Definitely check that out.